# keep only the rows l, l+1, ... ,r in the matrix and deallocate the rest

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I want to keep only the rows l, l+1, ... r in the matrix and deallocate the rest
ex:

```
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8
9 0 1 2
```

for l=1 and r=2 the output is:

```
5 6 7 8 
9 0 1 2
```

This is what I tried:

```
void select_rows(int ***a, int *n, int m, int l, int r) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (r - l + 1); ++i)
            for(int j = 0; j<m; j++)
                a[i][j] = a[l+i][j];
    for (int i = r + 1; i <= *n; ++i) {
        free((*a)[i]);
       }
    if (*a == NULL) {
        return;
    *n = r - l + 1;
    }
}

int **create(int n, int m, int L, int R)
{
    int **a = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    if (a == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        a[i] = calloc(m, sizeof(int));
        if (a == NULL) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            a[i][j] = rand() % (R - L + 1) + L;
    return a;
}

int main(){ 
int n = 5, m = 4, L = -1, R = 3;
int **a = create(n, m, L, R);
int l = 2, r = 3;
select_rows(a, &n, m, l, r);
print(a, n, m);
return 0;
}
```

this is the whole program. The function create works but select_rows makes the program to crash.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (i.e. program with a `main()`) so we can see how you allocate the matrix.

Comment: You can't free parts of memory. You either free *all* the memory (allocated with `malloc`) or none at all.

Comment: And what is the actual problem you need to solve? Perhaps it can be solve another way? Perhaps copy the data you need to a *new* matrix? Your question is unfortunately an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) right now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If the rows are allocated individually it would work.

Comment: Also please note that being a [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not something to strive for.

Comment: It's still not a [mre]. Show us a program that we can compile as-is. `if (a == NULL) { return 1;` is just wrong. It should be `return NULL;` and in the second case, `if (a[i] == NULL) { return NULL; }` after freeing the first allocation. Note `a[i]` not `a`.

Comment: It's _still_ not a [mre] but for every bit you show, you show more errors. `select_rows(a, &n, m, l, r);` should _at least_ get a warning from the compiler. if it doesn't warn, turn on more compiler warnings and fix them.

Comment: After `free((*a)[i])`, what will you do with `(*a)[i]`? Where does it point? What happens if the rest of the code tries to dereference that pointer?

Comment: Also the check `if (*a == NULL)` is happening in the wrong place.

Comment: It will probably lead to undefined behaviour. So that is the reason why the program is crashing. But I do not realize where I am accessing that part of memory.

Comment: `select_rows` expects `int***`, but the call passes an `int**`. That can never work. Also, hardly anyone can handle a `***` properly, four stars actually working is at the Nobel Prize level. Please simplify the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the results in a new [r-l+1][y]matrix like this:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void dispMatrixVar(int row, int col, int **matrix){
    // Printing out the matrix
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<col; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int** select_rows(int row, int col, int matrix[row][col], int l, int r) {
    int new_rows = r-l+1;
    int i;
    
    // Creating an empty matrix of size [r-l+1][x]
    int** new_matrix = malloc(sizeof(int*) * new_rows);
    for (i = 0; i < new_rows; ++i)
        new_matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * col);
    
    // Filling the values with the previous matrix
    for (int i=l; i<=r; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<col; j++){
            new_matrix[i-l][j] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    return new_matrix;
}

int main()
{
    int matrix[4][4] = {
        {1,2,3,4},
        {5,6,7,8},
        {9,0,1,2},
        {3,4,5,6}
    };
    
    int l = 1;
    int r = 2;
    int newRows = r-l+1;
    
    int **new = select_rows(4,4, matrix, l,r);
    dispMatrixVar(newRows, 4, new);

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```cpp
5 6 7 8 
9 0 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NEW_ARRAY(pointer, length) \
    { \
        (pointer) = malloc(((size_t) length) * sizeof (pointer)[0]); \
        if ((pointer) == NULL) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n"); \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
        } \
    }

void select_rows(int **a, int *m, int n, int l, int r)
{
    int i;

    assert(l >= 0);
    assert(r >= l);
    assert(r < *m);

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        free(a[i]);
    }
    for (i = r + 1; i < *m; i++) {
        free(a[i]);
    }
    for (i = l; i <= r; i++) {
        a[i - l] = a[i];
    }
    *m = r - l + 1;
}


int main(void)
{
    int **a, m = 3, n = 4, i, j;

    /*create matrix*/
    NEW_ARRAY(a, m);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        NEW_ARRAY(a[i], n);
    }
    a[0][0] = 1; a[0][1] = 2; a[0][2] = 3; a[0][3] = 4;
    a[1][0] = 5; a[1][1] = 6; a[1][2] = 7; a[1][3] = 8;
    a[2][0] = 9; a[2][1] = 0; a[2][2] = 1; a[2][3] = 2;

    /*select rows to keep*/
    select_rows(a, &m, n, 1, 2);

    /*print new matrix*/
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf(" %d", a[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    /*free matrix*/
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        free(a[i]);
    }
    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```